# Logging out but the previous user's credentials are there in page instead of current user, untill i refresh the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jwt, local-storage, vuex

In vue.js when I logged out from one user and login from another user it is showing the previous user's id (acces token) instead of current user's until I refresh the page.
I am using localstorage.removeItem() method.

```
    Here it is login function                                                            


    async userLogin({ commit }, userObj) {
        const response = await axios(api.auth.signIn(userObj));
        localStorage.setItem(
          'userTokens',
          JSON.stringify({
            access: response.data.access,
            refresh: response.data.refresh,
          }),
        );
        commit(LOGIN, response.data);
      },





    And is logout function                                                                                            

      async userLogout({ commit }) {
        try {
          console.log('object');
          localStorage.removeItem('userTokens');
          commit(LOGOUT);
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn(e);
        }
      },


   Dont know the issue.
```

Comment: What is the previous user's IDs not being cleared from? Just local storage, or do you have some other Vuex state that is caching the data? Either way, the issue lies elsewhere in code that you have not provided so it'll be difficult to help you.

Comment: yes the previous user's ids saves. it's my vuex all code  on mutation. only i use mutation and action 

  [LOGOUT]: (state) => {
    state.isLoggedIn = false;
    state.access = undefined;
    state.refresh = undefined;
  },